# Is it possible to speed up the changing of IP addresses when using Tor package in Node.js / Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, tor

I am changing my IP via Tor in a Node.js / Puppeteer application every cycle/loop.

Currently, the IP is changing every 5-10 minutes when calling `await exec('(echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc 127.0.0.1 9050');`.

Code:
`const exec = require('child_process').exec;`
then 
`await exec('(echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc 127.0.0.1 9050');` is called to request a new Tor circuit.

I need to have a new IP (non repeating) every minute or so. How can this be accomplished? **I am open to moving away from Tor if there is a more viable option.**

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Change MaxCircuitDirtiness in your torrc file. You can just add it if it's not there. For example, to change route every 2 minutes:

MaxCircuitDirtiness 120

The default is 10 minutes, so the value is 600.

Just remember that it guarantees tor will try a new circuit - this does not always mean a new ip!